# What is Terminal role in a machine?

Tags: terminal

I am new in Terminal or bash, so I have really hard time to understanding the role that Terminal has in computer/mac, I do not know that should I consider Terminal as an OS or as a programing language. For example if we look at macOS, it is an OS for mac machine and in the other hand Xcode is the programing language. I can understand those, but I cannot find the position of Terminal in between, need some information and explain about Terminal or bash to understand its purpose of existing.

Comment: [What is the exact difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell', a 'tty' and a 'console'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126/108618)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A terminal is a text only way to interact with the OS. It is useful if you know all the commands and want to quickly check something.

Where the OS GUI may change due to an update the terminal commands don't. In linux for example, everything can be done with just terminal, and the GUI is optional. For Windows, before Windows even existed, the OS was MS-DOS.

All commands from MS-DOS are still possible even in the Command Prompt. PowerShell can do a lot more specific OS things though.

To give an example for Windows. If I were to find out how long a computer is up and running, I could go deep into various settings screens and control panel to find the info somewhere hidden in a dialog, or I could open a command prompt and type `net stats workstation` and get the answer quickly in less than 20 seconds.

An additional bonus is that these commands that you enter in a terminal can often be scheduled too. So you can automate your workflow based on how you would enter the commands in the terminal manually, but instead, place them inside a script, and setup a schedule to execute that script at regular intervals.

Comment: Thanks for info, after reading your answer, I see that I must consider Terminal as an OS in Text way, do we get often update for Terminal? also is Terminal name or program is just reserved for apple Terminal? lastly does macOS need Terminal to be usable or Terminal is just a tool or keyboard for human to communicate with cpu and in the fact macOS can work without it?

Comment: Terminal is not an OS, it is a tool to interact with the OS similar to use the mouse and click anywhere. I don't think there will be updates for terminal, at least not to add new commands. But any program installed may add features to terminal. Terminal is a unix and linux name. Given that MacOS is based on Unix, that's why its called terminal. Its not limited to that. MacOS could probably live without terminal, but it may break some stuff if it were really gone.

Comment: Thanks for information.